# Why does a Javascript variable not have an object pass by reference?

Tags: javascript

I'm passing an object into a function. I'm pulling out a property of the object which is a sub object for easy reading. However, that second object does not effect it's analogous property on the first object. Why is this?

I want the processItem.event outside of the function scope to be updated when the event is saved. Why do have to update processItem and not just the local variable which points to it?

This works:

```
this.submitForm = function(processItem) {
    var event = processItem.event
    if (event.new) {
        EventDataService.create(event).then(function(response) {
            processItem.event = response.data;
        });
    } else {
        EventDataService.update(event).then(function(response) {
            processitem.event = response.data
        });
    }
};
```

and this doesn't

```
this.submitForm = function(processItem) {
    var event = processItem.event
    if (event.new) {
        EventDataService.create(event).then(function(response) {
            event = response.data;
        });
    } else {
        EventDataService.update(event).then(function(response) {
            event = response.data
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: JavaScript provides so called [`Call by sharing`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing). In case 1, you change the property of an original object. In case 2, you simply reassign the reference without changing `processItem`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var event = processItem.event
```

Now `event` refers to the same thing as `processItem.event`

```
event = response.data
```

Now `event` refers to the same thing as `response.data`, and does not refer to the same thing as `processItem.event` any more. It is very different from

```
processItem.event = response.data
```

which would make `processItem.event` co-refer with `response.data` (but not with `event` any more).

This has nothing to do with function arguments, but with the fact that JavaScript has references, and not aliases.